# How to use Group by and Concate with multiple records against single id

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables.

1. students
2. groups
3. group_members

I will show all student data to table with their joined group name.
May be student have joined to many groups and i want to show their group name in one table column with comma.

This is my SQL code:

```
SELECT `users`.*,`groups`.`gr_name`,`id` as `uid` FROM `users` 
LEFT JOIN `group_members` ON `users`.`id` = `group_members`.`gm_telebe` 
LEFT JOIN `groups` ON `group_members`.`gm_group` = `groups`.`gr_id` 
WHERE `users`.`level` < 5 GROUP by `id` 
ORDER by `reg_date` DESC;
```

If i remove `GROUP by id` then i will get all result with repeated table row.
But i want to show every student name 1 time.

Can you show me my mistake in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP_CONCAT` will concat the values separated by comma.

Here is the modified query:

```
SELECT `users`.*, GROUP_CONCAT(`groups`.`gr_name`) AS group_name, `id` as `uid`
FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `group_members` ON `users`.`id` = `group_members`.`gm_telebe`
LEFT JOIN `groups` ON `group_members`.`gm_group` = `groups`.`gr_id`
WHERE `users`.`level` < 5 GROUP by `id` ORDER by `reg_date` DESC;
```

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat